# (Unity C#) How would I convert a 3-dimensional array to a single array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a square grid that get's generated with widths x, y, and z and is comprised of Nodes.

Before I had a 3-Dimensional Node[,,] to store the grid, but I needed to be able to save the grid on edit-time, and multidimensional arrays can't be. I was just wondering how I would convert the x, y, and z coordinates for a Node into an index for a single array.

Thanks, and I hope this is enough information for you

Comment: you mean an array with one dimension? or do you want to create an array where you can can find a variable using x,y,z?

Comment: An array with one dimension, I have a function to get the x, y, and z coordinates, but I need the array to be single-dimensional to be able to be saved

Comment: Typically such mapping is done by doing something like this `index = x + y * maxX + z * maxX * maxY`. The reverse is done with integer division and modulo operators. Not sure though if that would work well with whatever you do with it in Unity.

Comment: 1D: `nodes[node.x]`, 2D: `nodes[(node.x * maximumY) + node.y]`, 3D: `nodes[(node.x * maximumY * maximumZ) + (node.y * maximumZ) + node.z]`

Comment: Do you know your grid size?

Comment: You know...if you create a 1D in the first place you can use it as 1D, 2D, 3D... or whatever.  It's all in the _stride._

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the feedback,

For anyone wondering, Luke Brigg's answer was correct. "`nodes[node.x], 2D: nodes[(node.x * maximumY) + node.y], 3D: nodes[(node.x * maximumY * maximumZ) + (node.y * maximumZ) + node.z]`"

I had a function which could get the x, y, and z coordinates for the 3-dimensional array, and by plugging them into the equation Luke posted, it gave the correct index for a 1-D array.

Thank you all for helping out!